# Background X on InDesign project

Tags: adobe-indesign, background

I am very new to in-design. While working on a template that a more experienced (and now gone) user set up for me, suddenly I have an 'X' in the background on every page. How do I remove this? See screen shot.
[image]

Comment: Check in the links panel if there's an unlinked image - a network file which is now unavailable. If you have a system adminstrator he may recover it from backups. Maybe unrelated: It's not at all uncommon that a worker leaves or at least tries to leave a mark which stays after he has been fired. If it happens to fit to this case you may have seen only the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: Could this be a Rectangle Frame with no image inside? That would have an "X" through the box, it doesn't print and only shows in InDesign. I would export the PDF and see if the X is still there.

Answer (score 1):

The `X` is merely showing the **image frame** for that *background mountain scene*, Its standard and *nothing* to be concerned about. It's a "guide" of sorts, not actual data that will output. Image frames have the X to let users know, while working, where the frame is.

Hit the <kbd>w</kbd> key on the keyboard to enter `Preview Mode` and the `x` won't be there.

If it *really* bothers you, you can choose `View > Extras > Hide Frame Edges` and it should go away. **However** hiding frame edges is often *more* confusing for new users.